# How do I return multiple 'scorers' when scraping for football results using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm just a few hours into learning Python so please go easy with me! I'm just wanting to scrape scores and scorers off a website, I've been able to do that, however, I'm only getting one scorer (if there is one!), when there are multiple goal scorers I am only getting the first.  I **think** I'm trying to look for multiple scorers under '# Home Scorers'.

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.skysports.com/football-results"

match_results = {}
match_details = {}
match_no = 0

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
matches = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'fixres__item'})

for match in matches:
    try:
        match_url_get = match.find('a',{'class':'matches__item matches__link'}).get('href')
        match_url = match_url_get if match_url_get else "unknown"
        event_id  = match_url[-6:]
        
        match_response = requests.get(match_url)
        match_data = match_response.text
        match_soup = BeautifulSoup(match_data,'html.parser')
        
        # Match Details
        match_date = match_soup.find('time',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__detail-time'}).text
        match_location = match_soup.find('span',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__detail-venue'}).text
        match_info = match_soup.find('p',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__detail-fixture'}).text
        
        # Home Scores & Team
        home_details = match_soup.find_all('span',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__team-name sdc-site-match-header__team-name--home'})
        for home_detail in home_details:    
            home_team = home_detail.find('span',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__team-name-block-target'}).text
            
        home_score_get = match_soup.find('span',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__team-score-block','data-update':'score-home'})
        home_score = home_score_get.text if home_score_get else "none"
        
        # Home Scorers
        home_scorer_details = match_soup.find_all('ul',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__team-synopsis','data-update':'synopsis-home'})
        for home_scorer_detail in home_scorer_details:    
            goal_scorer_get = home_scorer_detail.find('li',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__team-synopsis-line'})
            goal_scorer = goal_scorer_get.text if goal_scorer_get else "none"
            goal_score_minute_get = home_scorer_detail.find('span',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__event-time'})
            goal_score_minute = goal_score_minute_get.text if goal_score_minute_get else "none"

         # Away Scores & Team   
        away_details = match_soup.find_all('span',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__team-name sdc-site-match-header__team-name--away'})
        for away_detail in away_details:    
            away_team = away_detail.find('span',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__team-name-block-target'}).text
        away_score_get = match_soup.find('span',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__team-score-block','data-update':'score-away'})
        away_score = away_score_get.text if away_score_get else "none"
        
        # Home Scorers
        away_scorer_details = match_soup.find_all('ul',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__team-synopsis','data-update':'synopsis-away'})
        for away_scorer_detail in away_scorer_details:    
            away_goal_scorer_get = away_scorer_detail.find('li',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__team-synopsis-line'})
            away_goal_scorer = away_goal_scorer_get.text if away_goal_scorer_get else "none"
            away_goal_score_minute_get = away_scorer_detail.find('span',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__event-time'})
            away_goal_score_minute = away_goal_score_minute_get.text if away_goal_score_minute_get else "none"
        
        print("Match: ",event_id , "Match Date:", match_date, "Match Location:", match_location, "Match Info:", match_info, "\nResult: ", home_team, home_score, away_team, away_score)
        print("Home Scorer:", goal_scorer, "Minute:",goal_score_minute, "\nAway Scorer:", away_goal_scorer, "Minute:",away_goal_score_minute)
        print(match_date)
        
    except:
        pass
    
    match_no+=1
    match_results[match_no] = [event_id, home_team, home_score, away_team, away_score, match_url, match_date, match_location, match_info]
    match_details[match_no] = [event_id, goal_scorer, goal_score_minute, away_goal_scorer, away_goal_score_minute]
    
    

Period = "2021-22"

print("Total Matches: ", match_no)

match_results = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(match_results, orient='index', columns = ['Event_ID:', 'Home Team:','Home Score:','Away Team:','Away Score:','Link:','Match Date:','Match Location:','Match Info:'])
match_results.to_csv("Python/FL/Premier League Results (SkySports.com) " + Period + ".csv")

match_details = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(match_details, orient='index', columns = ['Event_ID:', 'Home Goal:','Home Goal Minute:','Away Goal:','Away Goal Minute:'])
match_details.to_csv("Python/FL/Premier League Details (SkySports.com) " + Period + ".csv")
```

So the bit that's not working correctly is:

```
        # Home Scorers
        home_scorer_details = match_soup.find_all('ul',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__team-synopsis','data-update':'synopsis-home'})
        for home_scorer_detail in home_scorer_details:    
            goal_scorer_get = home_scorer_detail.find('li',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__team-synopsis-line'})
            goal_scorer = goal_scorer_get.text if goal_scorer_get else "none"
            goal_score_minute_get = home_scorer_detail.find('span',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__event-time'})
            goal_score_minute = goal_score_minute_get.text if goal_score_minute_get else "none"
```

Any ideas how I can return multiple rows for that bit?!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your expected result?

Comment: If there are 3 x Goal Scorers, then 3 rows, each with the Name and the Minute scored. I'm only one row at present.

Comment: Check you for loops, looks like you will be overwriting the `goal_scorer_get` variable within each loop.

Comment: Yeah it's the bit labelled 'So the bit that's not working correctly is:' @Xitiz

Comment: @Quixotic22 I wondered that, but it's the first goal scorer that's being recorded, not the subsequent scorers, so it's not over-writing it's just not looking for any additional (or not finding them), but the class is identical so I can't see how it can't find them. And I thought the 'for home_scorer_detail in home_scorer_details: ' would keep it looking for more...

Comment: @Xitiz I'd rather not get help from you if you're going to be rude. I've literally been using python for about 5 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`home_scorer_details` only has 1 item, the unordered list itself.

To get all the scorers you need to get the items in that list.

The following code, which is pretty rough, will create a list of dictionaries where each dictionary has the name of the scorer and the minute(s) they scored.

You could use similar code to get all the away scorers.

Like I said, this code is rough and needs refined but it should give you a start.

```py
        # Home Scorers
        home_scorer_details = match_soup.find_all('ul',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__team-synopsis','data-update':'synopsis-home'})
        home_scorers = []

        for home_scorer_detail in home_scorer_details[0].find_all('li'):    
            goal_scorer = home_scorer_detail.text
            goal_score_minute_get = home_scorer_detail.find('span',{'class':'sdc-site-match-header__event-time'})
            goal_score_minute = goal_score_minute_get.text if goal_score_minute_get else "none"
            home_scorers.append({'scorer': goal_scorer, 'minute': goal_score_minute})
        print(home_scorers)
```